# Request for reopen question 352656

Tags: support, reopen-request, off-topic

It was [closed as off-topic by being mobile question](https://superuser.com/questions/352656/bulk-installer-for-windows-mobile), but in fact it is an windows software question to find a software to handle bulk installation/setup for several similar devices.

I rewrote the question to be more clear and on topic.

Answer (score 8):

Are you sure?

I've read the question about 4 times now, and I still don't get remotely get the impression that is what your asking. Even your clarification still implies it is a device issue.

Your question reads that your trying to find a single installation for all the apps on the device rather then software that will be able to push the same settings and software to all the devices in bulk.

Put some more thought into the question, supply a bit more details, ie. It's a corporate environment, are you or aren't you using exchange, will it be via a corporate network etc etc etc and then it can seriously be considered to be reopened.

In it's current form, we are simply forced to make an assumption.

Comment: I think it is very much a grey area and I do not know the correct answer, but I am on the side of whatever the mods choose... I think the phrasing implies a device/non pc question, however, the actual answer is very much PC related... To use Microsoft System Centre Device Manager (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Center_Mobile_Device_Manager )...

Comment: I think the `"What is the best way to install and set up several Windows Mobile devices with the same software and settings?"` Part of the question is what really causes this.. It doesn't really indicate anything to do with using computers.